# Can't understand How to decide when to use Hidden() and when to use HiddenFor()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper, hidden-field

I am following a book and here is the code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RemoveFromCart", "Cart"))
{
    @Html.Hidden("ProductId", line.Product.ProductID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ReturnUrl)
    <input class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" type="submit" value="Remove" />
}
```

And here is also his explanation for why he has used `Hidden` instead of `HiddenFor`

[image]

but still I can't understand the wiring behind it that he is talking about. Can you elaborate this a little more ?

```
public RedirectToRouteResult RemoveFromCart(Cart cart, int productId, string returnUrl)
```

Comment: What does your `Model` look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remember that these helpers are just ways of generating HTML markup.

Example of the generated markup:

```
@Html.Hidden("ProductId", line.Product.ProductID)
```

**Generates:**
    `<input type="hidden" name="ProductId" value="5" />`

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Product.ProductID)
```

**Generates:**
    `<input type="hidden" name="Product_ProductId" value="5" />`

Your controller defines a parameter named `productId`. In order for model binding to work, the `name` value of the hidden input must match the argument name.

`Product_ProductId` will not match the defined argument `productId`for the `RemoveFromCart` Controller Action.

*It is worth noting that model binding is case insensitive.* So your hidden input value of `ProductId` will still bind to the `RemoveFromCart` parameter of `productId`.

Answer (score 1):

in your `RemoveFromCart(Cart cart, int productId, string returnURL)` you have an explicit variable, specifically `int productId`.  It would be expecting a field called `"ProductId` in the HTML in order to fill the value in.  If you use the `Html.HiddenFor` helper, it generates the field with the **full name** of the variable, resulting in an HTML field called `"Product_ProductID"`.  The model binder would not be able to match the HTML with this field name to the correct parameter in your function call.

Answer (score 1):

Use HiddenFor if your ViewModel property just has to be passed through view without any complicated processing.

The "Hidden" method is more custom way of data binding and is not necessarily related to your ViewModel but to a Form.

The "HiddenFor" method is just automated way of direct binding of ViewModel properties.